# different positioning between Chrome/Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-float

I have the following layout:-

**html:**-

```
 <header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="headerContainer">
            <div class="headerProfileNotifications">
                <img src="Images/" alt="notification" />
            </div>
            <div class="headerProfilePhoto">
                <img src="Images/" alt="profile_photo" />
            </div>
            <div class="headerProfileDetails">
                <div class="headerProfileName">John Smith</div>
                <div class="headerProfileEmail">john.smith@someemail.co.uk</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**and css:-**

```
    header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
   }

    #headerContainer {
    height: 33px;
    background-position: 10px 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
   }


    .headerProfileNotifications {
    float: right;
    height: 22px;
    width: 29px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
   }

    .headerProfilePhoto {
    float: right;
    height: 33px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: 5px;
   }


    .headerProfileDetails {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
   }

    .headerProfileName {
    margin-top: 2px;
    float: right;
   }


    .headerProfileEmail {
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7ekM/)

however it looks the same in `Chrome/Firefox,` and its looking the way it should be, but in `IE,` its displaying differently.

What `css` do I have to apply to `IE` to look exactly the same like `Chrome/Firefox?`

**Thanks for** your help and time

Comment: Hava you try 'IE conditional stylesheet'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
  .headerProfileEmail {
    clear:both;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: In this case it is necessary to move to a new line since there is a previous floating element. If you remove clear:both it will float next to .headerProfileName :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandro.  So clear:both is to move to a new line.

Comment: If there is an element to the left of an element you are defining you would use clear:left to go to the next line. If there was an element to the right of an element you are defining you would use clear:right. so if there was an element in the middle of 2 elements you would use clear:both... or just use clear:both to cover your bases :)